# LEFT OUTER JOIN + WHERE clause in Couchbase

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I am trying to perform a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`  while filtering on the right part of the join.

I have created the following index to achieve this:

```
CREATE INDEX `idx_store_order` ON `myBucket`(("Store::" || `storeId`)) WHERE ((`docType` = "Order") or (`docType` is missing))
```

and I am trying to execute the following query:

```
SELECT store.status, order.clientId, store.docId 
FROM myBucket store
LEFT OUTER JOIN myBucket order ON KEY ("Store::" || order.storeId) FOR store
WHERE store.docType="Store"
AND (order.docType="Order" OR order.docType IS MISSING)
AND order.clientId="9281ae36-a418-4ea3-93f0-bfd7b1a38248"
```

I have 30 documents with `docType="Store"`, but when I perform this query I don't get the 30 results. If I remove the last clause and group by store, then I get the 30 results, so it's the last clause that affects the final results.

I have also tried the following statement (unsucessfully) as the last clause:

`(AND order.clientId="9281ae36-a418-4ea3-93f0-bfd7b1a38248" OR order.docType IS MISSING)`

Am I missing something? Thanks

**EDIT**
Here's the explain query:

```
[
  {
    "plan": {
      "#operator": "Sequence",
      "~children": [
        {
          "#operator": "IndexScan",
          "index": "idx_docType",
          "index_id": "e498d0c0ee2f0d9d",
          "keyspace": "myBucket",
          "namespace": "default",
          "spans": [
            {
              "Range": {
                "High": [
                  "\"Store\""
                ],
                "Inclusion": 3,
                "Low": [
                  "\"Store\""
                ]
              }
            }
          ],
          "using": "gsi"
        },
        {
          "#operator": "Parallel",
          "~child": {
            "#operator": "Sequence",
            "~children": [
              {
                "#operator": "Fetch",
                "as": "store",
                "keyspace": "myBucket",
                "namespace": "default"
              },
              {
                "#operator": "IndexJoin",
                "as": "order",
                "for": "store",
                "keyspace": "myBucket",
                "namespace": "default",
                "on_key": "(\"Store::\" || (`order`.`storeId`))",
                "outer": true,
                "scan": {
                  "index": "idx_store_order",
                  "index_id": "a97fce5158e6e573",
                  "using": "gsi"
                }
              },
              {
                "#operator": "Filter",
                "condition": "((((`store`.`docType`) = \"Store\") and (((`order`.`docType`) = \"Order\") or ((`order`.`docType`) is missing))) and (((`order`.`clientId`) = \"9281ae36-a418-4ea3-93f0-bfd7b1a138248\") or (`order` is missing)))"
              },
              {
                "#operator": "InitialProject",
                "result_terms": [
                  {
                    "expr": "(`store`.`status`)"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "#operator": "FinalProject"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "text": "SELECT store.status\nFROM myBucket store\nLEFT OUTER JOIN myBucket order ON KEY (\"Store::\" || order.storeId) FOR store\nWHERE store.docType=\"Store\"\nAND (order.docType=\"Order\" OR order.docType IS MISSING)\nAND (order.clientId=\"9281ae36-a418-4ea3-93f0-bfd7b1a138248\" OR order IS MISSING)"
  }
]
```

**EDIT2**

As discussed in the comments, I want to list all stores, regardless of a given customer having orders in it or not. If the customer does have orders, then I want to show certain fields along with the list of stores.

*E.g.*
Store 1 - Client X does not have orders
Store 2 - Client X does have one order, and some information is shown along the store info

Comment: Try this query:  `SELECT count(*) FROM myBucket WHERE clientId="9281ae36-a418-4ea3-93f0-bfd7b1a38248"`.  Is the result more than 1?

Comment: @quest4truth Without specifying the docType, yes, it is more than 1. In this particular scenario, the client doesn't have any orders, but since I am performing a LOJ I was expecting that the stores would still be returned as a result

Comment: The WHERE clause is evaluated after the LEFT OUTER JOIN, so your result set will still be pared accordingly.  See https://www.bennadel.com/blog/70-sql-query-order-of-operations.htm for an explanation of how the SELECT statement gets executed

Answer (score 1):

Outer joins produce all left side documents irrespective of successfully matching the join-key predicate (and not any condition in your where-clause). That means, you get 30 results whether you have matching order.storeId or not.

In this case, the last filter is on client-ID, which is applied post JOIN, and hence is filtering some documents. Check/post the EXPLAIN output to validate.

Comment: I have updated my answer with the explain query. Even if I am filtering on the set with 30 results, shouldn't the `OR order IS MISSING` part keep the 30 results? If not, how can achieve the expected result? Thank you

Comment: What is your objective?  Are you trying to figure out how it works, or are the actual results the first priority?  If the actual results are paramount, please describe what you expect.

Comment: @quest4truth The actual results are the first priority. I expect to always have the results on the left (Stores), and have results on the right only if they exist (Orders). Since there are multiple Orders per Store, I was trying to filter per clientId. While filtering per clientId, I still expect to have 30 results in the end, due to the fact I stated in my previous comment

Comment: OK, but that's a contradiction.  You can't have 30 results if you filter those results by a customer that doesn't have 30 records.  The LOJ happens before the filter.  The filter deletes them after that LOJ happens. Do you just want orders by store by customer?  If the customer is not there, what do you want?  What's the purpose of filtering by customer if you want everything whether the customer is there or not?  Surely you don't want to ascribe orders to a customer that are not his.

Comment: Makes sense what what you're saying; what I need is to do the LOJ on two different fields (which I don't think is possible in couchbase). The client always exists - it's just that he may not have a relationship with the store yet. In that scenario, I still want to show the stores.

In a more concrete way, I want to show all the stores, and if the user as a relationship with it (orders) then show info about them as well (I'll update the question with this info). Does it make more sense now?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense.  Let me see if I can come up with a query

Comment: You can join on multiple fields like this:  `SELECT stuff FROM place LEFT OUTER JOIN 2ndPlace ON {key clause} LEFT OUTER JOIN 3rdPlace ON {nextkeyclause}`.  I won't try to post an answer because I don't understand the ON KEY part...

Comment: Hey @quest4truth. performing the second join on the client information will retrieve the user information, which is not what I want. In couchbase, the joins are performed on the document's key, hence the difficulties I am having so far (you can't join on a document's property).

Answer (score 0):

In N1QL currently, WHERE clause is not considered part of the JOIN predicate, so you have to do the following. You need to escape **order** throughout, or use a different alias.

```
SELECT store.status, order.userId, store.docId 
FROM myBucket store
LEFT OUTER JOIN myBucket order ON KEY ("Store::" || order.storeId) FOR store
WHERE store.docType="Store"
AND (
(order IS MISSING)
OR
 ((order.docType="Order" OR order.docType IS MISSING)
AND order.clientId="9281ae36-a418-4ea3-93f0-bfd7b1a38248")
```